# Static image path in sass

Tags: less, sass

In less you could always do this. You make a variable for the image path, and than you can insert the image path in the background url. How can I make this in SASS?

```
@static-path:           "../../static";
background: url("@{static-path}/img/bg-header.jpg") repeat-x left bottom;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SASS we define variables with $.

So define variable called path `$img_path: "../../static";`.

Then use something called interpolation ([sass docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)):

`background: url("#{static-path}/img/bg-header.jpg") repeat-x left bottom;`

When you are using COMPASS in your project you may use image-url() instead of url(), which grabs your image path from COMPASS config file.